# Powershell - Error handling (Dont invoke finally block if Catch block has been invoked)

Tags: powershell

In Powershell, it seem like it will always execute Finally block. Is there a way to tell Powershell not execute statement in Finally block if Catch block 
has been executed. Example my below code, if email has been trigger then I don't want powershell generate log file.

```
Catch
{
$ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
$FailedItem = $_.Exception.ItemName
Send-MailMessage -From xxxxxxxxxx
Break
}

Finally
{
$Time=(Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')
"This script made a read attempt at" +  "$d1" | out-file $logfile -append
}
```

Comment: This is antithetical to the concept of 'finally'.  It sounds like what you have in your finally block should be at the end of your try block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not endorse using this code, but to answer your question, yes, it is possible doing something like this.

```
$badIdea = $true

try
{
    Write-Output "About to do something dumb."
    $ugh = 1 / 0;
    Write-Output "Did I do something dumb?"
}
catch
{
    Write-Output "Caught something dumb."
    $badIdea = $false
}
finally
{
    if ($badIdea -eq $true)
    {
        Write-Output "Performing finally..."
    }
    else 
    {
        Write-Output "Skipping finally..."
    }
}
```

Code does what you tell it...and you can use conditional statements anywhere you want.

This produces:

```
About to do something dumb.
Caught something dumb.
Skipping finally...
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Now I know how to rewrite my code. Thanks

Comment: @user664481: I recommend focusing on the "I do not endorse using this code" part of the answer - Kory's approach is only called for in _unusual_ scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the `Finally` clause is to *always* execute, *whether an exception 
occurred or not*.

Thus, as [Jason Boyd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1937249/jason-boyd) points out in a comment on the question, you would typically place code you only want executed if *no* exception occurred *after* the `try` statement.

`break` in your `Catch` handler ensures that any code below the `try` statement is only reached in case *no* exception occurred - but note that `break` simply breaks out of any *enclosing loop* - even across function and script boundaries(!); only if there is no enclosing loop is `break` equivalent to exiting the enclosing script.

Comment: I agree.  That said, there could be valid reasons to have some conditional code in a finally.  Without knowing the exact situation, hard to say, but of course, that does seem counter to the finally...moving on...

Comment: @KoryGill: True, we don't know the exact situation, but, based on the way the question is phrased, I suspect a lack of understanding of the fundamentals.